# How to integrate $\int_0^{2\pi } \ln \vert z - \frac{\pi}{2} \vert d\theta$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Compute $$\int_0^{2\pi } \ln \vert z - \tfrac{\pi}{2}  \vert d\theta$$ for $z=\pi e^{i\theta}$. (Here the $\ln$ is natural logarithm.)

Since $dz = \pi i e^{i\theta} d\theta$. Therefore, $d\theta = \frac{dz}{zi}$.

Therefore, $$\int_0^{2\pi } \ln \vert z - \tfrac{\pi}{2}  \vert d\theta =  \int _{\vert z\vert =\pi} \frac {\ln\vert  z - \frac{\pi}{2}  \vert }{zi} dz $$

I can't proceed for next step anymore. What should I do next to find that value?

Comment: Surely the contour is $|z|=\pi$.

Comment: You can use the fact that your integral is $
{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} \int_0^{2\pi } {\log \left( {\pi e^{i\theta }  - \frac{\pi }{2}} \right)d\theta } .
$

Comment: @J.G., Yes that was the typo. I edited.

Comment: How did you get the last equality?

Comment: @Gary.  In fact I've got some that from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238272/integral-of-complex-logarithm.  But  I'll deleted it if  that does not hold.

Comment: @kechanglee It seems that you did not completely understand the derivation in that question.

Comment: @Gary. Exactly! I deleted it.